# A question on raining probability using conditional probability

Tags: probability, bayesian, naive-bayes

When A predicts raining, the chance of raining is 60%. When B predicts 
raining, the chance of raining is also 60%. If A and B both predict to rain 
(assuming they did the prediction independently), what is the chance of raining?

My understanding of the problem is as follows:

Let $X, Y, Z$ respectively denote the events of A predicts raining, B predicts raining, and it does rain. Then we have:
$$P(Z|X)=P(Z|Y)=.6,\,P(XY)=P(X)P(Y).$$
We need to find out $P(Z|X,Y)$.

I could not figure out how to calculate the it. Maybe I can only get a range of it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Did: It seems to me that the parenthetical qualification essentially says that your second scenario obtains. It certainly excludes your first.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes. Nevertheless, a hypothesis is missing...

Answer (score 4):

Let $X,Y,Z$ be the events that $A$ predicts rain, $B$ rpredicts rain, it rains.
We are given that $X,Y$ are independant and $P(Z|X)=P(Z|Y)=0.6$.

It could be that $P(X)=P(Y)=0.6$ and $Z=X\cap Y$. In that case $P(Z|A,B)=1$.

It could also be that $P(X)=P(Y)=0.4$ and $Z=\overline{X\cap Y}$. In that case $P(Z|A,B)=0$.

And anything inbetween is possible.

Comment: You are right. Thanks.